# Enter an object into a FormPage

Tags: chemistry, formpage

I am currently trying to make a FormPage that plots a Molecule and I try to add a possibility to input a custom Molecule.

Entering the data for a Molecule makes Mathematica crash.

Code:
FormPage["m"->Molecule,MoleculePlot@#m&]

An input that works is e.g. Benzene
but things like {"H","H"},{Bond[{1,2}]} made Mathematica crash.

It doesn't crash anymore but I get
MoleculePlot: Argument Molecule[{"H","H"},{Bond[{1,2}]}] is not a valid molecule.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify that the input can be a Mathematica expression. However, `{"H", "H"}, {Bond[{1, 2}]}` is not really a valid expression, and it must be wrapped in another list `{{"H", "H"}, {Bond[{1, 2}]}}`. Then you can do it as following:

```
FormPage["m" -> ToExpression, MoleculePlot[Molecule @@ #m] &]
```

[image: FormPage]

The drawback now is that you have to input `"benzene"` with the quotemarks. You can solve this by setting `m` to be a string, then checking if it includes curly braces, and parse it to expression afterwards with `ToExpression`. And since we are already making a somehow unelegant workaround, let's also manually include the curly brackets.

```
FormPage["m" -> String,
 MoleculePlot[
   Molecule @@ 
    If[StringContainsQ[#m, "{"], 
     ToExpression["{" <> #m <> "}"], {#m}]] &]
```

[image: FormPage with parsing expression]